# empty lists for all_attributes and all_methods in sphinx

Tags: python, jinja2, python-sphinx

I'm trying to show separately the attributes and methods for each class with sphinx. 
But when using my template I notice that both `{{ all_attributes }}` and `{{ all_methods }}` are empty.

Digging inside the code I notice that to determine whether an item of `dir(obj)` is a method or an attribute, the `sphinx.ext.autosummary.get_documenter` function is called on the item, but my debug pretty much ended there.

Does anyone know what might be the reason for sphinx not being able to identify if the elements I have are methods or attributes?

Comment: Maybe you should write a question (issue) to the Sphinx project.